# env is not working in Windows to set port for ExpressJS is there any solution?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am deploying app on heroku and this app need to listen random port as someone download it. For that I need dynamic port so, env is working well in Linux and OSX but I need to know how to use same in Windows because env is not supporting in Windows! Help me out :)

This is My Code:

```
const port = process.env.port || 3000; //sets to 3000 but I need to make it dynamic

console.log(process.env.port);// undefined if I remove OR(||) in above statement
```

Comment: Check the environment variable is set or not on windows machine with the name port and having the respective port value. You can set it from system properties as well as from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you didn't set the env in windows correctly. It should be something like this:

```
"start_windows": "set port=3333&&node index.js"
```

or use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) so you can set them the same for all platforms